# Linkedin API - user data parsing after consent

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to use the LinkedIn API with Auth0 to get the bearer token after a User agrees, and then use this token to retrieve all information in the user's profile (not just first and last name, etc., but also previous experiences, studies, etc.).
I managed to get only the basic information, but I cannot find any updated documentation about retrieving the rest of the account public data (if it's possible).
Is my use case possible? Do I need to register my company to be an affiliate customer to retrieve all the information?
I tried to contact Linkedin sales and they sent me here on stackoverflow, so could someone give me an idea of the price/contracts involved in being an affiliate customer?

Thank you very much
Simone

I followed some docs and managed to get the agreement page with auth0 (`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization`) and exchange it with a token (`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`) but then the endpoint `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo` returns only basic information (name, surname, email)...

I contacted Linkedin's sales for info about the affiliate program but they told me to ask on stackoverflow at first.